# Meteor and Iron Router: raise 404 when id doesn't exist

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm using Iron Router for my urls and I have this route:

```
this.route('regionEdit', {
  path: '/region/:_id',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('region', this.params._id);
  },
  data: function() {
    return Regions.findOne({
      _id: this.params._id
    });
  }
});
```

This works fine when I use this path `http://example.com/region/xgok3Etc5mfhtmD7j`

Where `xgok3Etc5mfhtmD7j` is the `_id` of region. However, when I access to `http://example.com/region/whatever`, the page renders normally, but without data.

How can I raise a 404 error for this?

Comment: This is talked about in iron-router issue [#237](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/237). It's possible to return a 404 response from the server but not from the client.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return 404 using Iron Router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27001298/how-to-return-404-using-iron-router)

Answer (score 8):

not a 404, but you can render a not found page by doing something like this.

```
this.route('regionEdit', {
  path: '/region/:_id',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('region', this.params._id);
  },
  data: function() {
    var region = Regions.findOne({
      _id: this.params._id
    });
    if(!region)
      this.render("notFound");
    else
      return region;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you can try [Plugins](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#plugins)

According to this documentation there is already a built in plugin for this issue

```
Router.plugin('dataNotFound', {notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'});
```

And it is described as

> This out-of-box plugin will automatically render the template named "notFound" if the route's data is falsey

Comment: I believe that this dataNotFound plugin has to do with template data, not with a missing route or template.

Comment: But @Braulio indicates the template is rendered correctly without data (which means data function returns false) if I am not missing anything. Anyway, I had the same case if I understand correctly and it worked for me.

Comment: You might be right. I'm not sure about the dataNotFound plugin, but I got it to work as a config parameter: `Router.configure({notFoundTemplate: '404'});`

Comment: The `Router.configure({notFoundTemplate: '404'});` template will only be rendered if a corresponding Route is not found. Since OP is using params, the route will be found, so will render, but with no data.

Answer (score 0):

In router.js

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate:'layout',
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'
});
```

Configure your router this way to solve the issue

and Template Part

```
<template name="notFound">
    <div class="container">

            <h1 class="colorWhite">Oopss..ss..ss..</h1>
            <p class="colorWhite">You are out of the world, let's go back</p>

    </div>
</template>
```

make it like this.. it should work, in fact, it works for me..

Answer (score -1):

I include a catch all route on my `Router.map`:

#### router.js

```
Router.map(function() {

    ... // other routes

    this.route('404', {
       path: '/*',
       layoutTemplate: 'application', // this actually lives in Router.configure();
       template: 'pageNotFound',
       onBeforeAction: function(){
          console.log('not found');
       }
    });
});
```

#### templates.html

```
<template name="pageNotFound">
    <div>
        <h2>404 - page not found</h2>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="application">
    <div>
        <h1>My Application</h1>

        {{> yield}}

    </div>
</template>
```

This `pageNotFound` template then gets rendered in the `{{> yeild}}` partial of the `application` template if none of the other routes pick up the uri path.

Comment: Ok. Any more details you can perhaps offer?