# How to return 404 using Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

When I hit a route that doesn't exist on my Meteor app that uses IR, I get a `200` response with an HTML that (when rendered on a browser) displays a js error on console saying that `No route found for path: "/aRoute"`.

How can a make it return `404`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There don't seem to be a correct (or even working?) way of handling real 404's right now. See this issue for example: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/1055

Even when you try ways which *should* work, you'll still end up with a 200 status code. Like this code below which should work:

```
this.route( 'pageNotFound', {
  path: '/(.*)',
  where: 'server',
  action: function() {
    this.response.writeHead(404);
    this.response.end( html );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! We'll have to wait for that issue to be solved.

Answer (score 7):

I find this much easier way to show page not found. In router.js

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: "layout",
    loadingTemplate: "loading",
    notFoundTemplate: "notFound"
})
```

Here "notFound" could be any template where you want to show 404 error

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to return an error code for another app to consume. Also, isn't this code for the client router instead of the server one?

Comment: no, this does *not* return a 404 status code, the code is still 200.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.route('template404', {
  path: '/*'
}
```

Use it at the end of your Router.map, cause this catches every value - if you use at the begining every path will be caught to this

Of course you can make it more complex, for example:

```
this.route('template404', {
      path: '/posts/*'
    }
```

Comment: I get the same errot with the first solution.

Comment: It doesn't work either. Do you have it working? on which version of Meteor/IR?