# handling 404 in Angular-Meteor

Tags: angularjs, node.js, meteor, angular-ui-router, angular-meteor

I'm using Angular-meteor using the Angular UI-Router and i cannot handle the `404` errors, I'm wondering if anybody had to deal with that specially it's `ABC` for SEO.

Currently i'm redirecting any not found entities to the route `/404` but with status code is `200`.

For more information i'm also using Meteor's `spiderable` package for rendering the page.

Also i found [Prerender.io](https://prerender.io) has their own solution using this metatag :

```
<meta name="prerender-status-code" content="404">
```

Will [Prerender](https://prerender.io) be my solution or there's another way without dealing with other services !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this issue by using [jazeee](https://github.com/jazeee)'s [spiderable-longer-timeout](https://atmospherejs.com/jazeee/spiderable-longer-timeout) fork. It adds the support for HTTP status errors by redirecting the user to a page that includes this HTML comment

```
<!-- response:status-code=404 -->
```

This way, we can ensure spiderable sends a 404 status code in the response headers

Answer (score 1):

I think Iron router has some built in functionality for this...
Or use router configure

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27001708/1535018

Comment: Angular doesnt use Iron Router

Comment: Meteor does...perhaps I'm Confused